# What does "APT" mean in box 34 of the WD AGO 53-55?

Tags: world-war-two

Reviewed my father's [WD AGO Form 53-55](https://www.cem.va.gov/hmm/discharge_documents.asp#:%7E:text=WD%20AGO%2053%2D55,of%20Separation%20Honorable%20Discharge) discharge papers from the army (Nov 1945).  Does anyone know what the acronym "APT" in block 34 mean.  Block 34 is titled "Wounds Received in Action".  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an image you can upload? APT usually would appear in box 36, indicates service in the [Asian Pacific Theater](https://www.80thdivision.com/pdfs/ReadingUnderstandingWWIIDischargeDocument.pdf).

Comment: Standard abbreviation for Armor Piercing Tracer

Comment: Box 34 is "Wounds Received in Action"  See here for that info https://www.80thdivision.com/pdfs/ReadingUnderstandingWWIIDischargeDocument.pdf.  See here for abbreviation  APT https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/Glossary/A.html

Answer (score 3):

80th division says  [Asian Pacific Theater](https://www.80thdivision.com/pdfs/ReadingUnderstandingWWIIDischargeDocument.pdf)

> Box 36 Service Outside Continental U.S. and Return
> Depart: = Date ship left loading port
> Destination: =
>
> > ETO = European Theater of Operations,
> > APT = Asiatic Pacific Theater;
> > MTO = Mediteranian Theater of Operations.
> > Arrive: Date ship arrived at port of destination/  These dates can be used to find ships or convoys.